# Number of independent KCL equations?

Tags: circuit-analysis

When using nodal analysis, my book says you will always end up with \$n-1\$ linearly independent equations, where \$n\$ is the number of nodes.

Can someone intuitively explain why this is true? If it's too hard too give intuition, I'll settle for a formal proof.